# Where should I place comma? "and thus"

Tags: punctuation, commas

I am a masters student studying wireless communication in Korea.
While writing my paper, I have encountered a problem about how to use English punctuation (the inclusion or not of a comma).

Can you tell me if I need a comma in the sentence I wrote, and if so, where I should put it – in front of or behind the "and thus"?

> The development and rapid growth of two-way interactive applications such as video call, real-time games, and Internet-of-Things (IoT) make it worse and thus we urgently need to find solutions to increasing the UL capacity.

Comment: There are issues bigger than punctuation with the sentence. "_...make it worse..." make what worse_?, for example.

Comment: Are you aware of how two independent clauses may be connected in a sentence? If not, then researching that issue should help.

Comment: A comma is expected, and thus will help.

Comment: I'd drop the 'and' and start another sentence at 'thus'. A colon might be appropriate instead but I'd drop the 'and' whatever you do.